# Laravel how to set a database environment variable?

Tags: laravel

I need to set a variable in my database every time a connection is opened, get a variable from the token and set the user

`SET app_user_id = Auth::id() ?? null;`

what is the correct place to set this variable, would be in the AppServiceProvider?

Comment: For what purpose? Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `DB::statement`. `Auth::id()` returns null if there is no authenticated user in the default guard, so  `?? null` is unnecessary.

Putting it in a service provider might work.

```php
public function boot()
{
    DB::statement('SET app_user_id = ?', [Auth::id()]);
}
```

However, I don't think this will work as you expect it to.

Every user is connecting to the same database and the app_user_id value will be overwritten.